# How to get update message/property from second level threads in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, binding, task

In a JavaFX application, I have a master thread which listens to the multiple clients through socket, and for each client connection separate thread is created for communication with the client. I want to display messages from all the clients on the JavaFX scene (through property binding or some other way). I tried with Task and Service as explained in the Concurrency in JavaFX tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm. I am able to get the message from the master thread through updateMessage, but couldn't figure out how to get the messages from the second level threads created for client communications. The sample code I tried is given below.

```
public class SocketService
    {
        int portNumber;

        public SocketService(int portNumber)
        {
            this.portNumber = portNumber;

            Task task = new Task<Void> ()
            {
                @Override
                public Void call()
                {
                    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber))
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            ClientService cs = new ClientService(serverSocket.accept());
                            cs.start();
                            updateMessage("Connected");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Exception!!! "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
           new Thread(task).start();
        }
    }

    class ClientService extends Service<Void>
    {
        Socket connectSocket;
        public ClientService(Socket connectSocket)
        {
            this.connectSocket = connectSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public Task<Void> createTask()
        {
            return new Task<Void>()
            {
                @Override public Void call()
                {
                    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connectSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectSocket.getInputStream()));)
                    {
                        String inText;

                        while ((inText = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(inText);
                            updateMessage(inText); // want to get this message updated in JavaFX
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Exception!!! "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the message property of the service you create. Notifications of changes to that property are executed on the FX Application Thread (note, as sort of an aside, you have a bug: you can only call `Service.start()` from the FX Application Thread; that is fixed here):

```
while (true) {
    ClientService cs = new ClientService(serverSocket.accept());
    cs.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMessage, newMessage) -> {
        // update UI with newMessage...
    }
    Platform.runLater(cs::start);
    updateMessage("Connected");
}
```

For a more sophisticated approach, you probably don't want to expose details of the UI to the `SocketService` class. So you might consider something like

```
public class SocketService {

    private final ObservableMap<ClientService, String> messageLookup 
        = FXCollections.observableMap(new HashMap<>()) ;

    private final ObservableList<String> messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<String> getMessages() { return messages ; }

    int portNumber ;

    public SocketService(int portNumber) {

        this.portNumber = portNumber ;

        messageLookup.addListener((Change<? extends ClientService, ? extends String> change) -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                messages.add(change.getValueAdded());
            }
            if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                messages.remove(change.getValueRemoved());
            }
        });

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) {
                    while(true) {
                        ClientService cs = new ClientService(serverSocket.accept());
                        cs.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMessage, newMessage) -> 
                            messageLookup.put(cs, newMessage));
                        Platform.runLater(cs::start);
                        updateMessage("Connected");
                    }
                } catch (...) { ... }
                return null ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now in your UI you can do things like

```
ListView<String> messages = new ListView<>();
SocketService socketService = ... ;
messages.setItems(socketService.getMessages());
```

Exactly how you use this depends, obviously, on what you're doing and how you want to display the status of the clients, but this should give you the idea.

Here is a complete, runnable example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TaskMessageUpdateExample extends Application {



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableMap<ClientService, String> messageLookup = FXCollections.observableMap(new HashMap<>());
        ObservableList<String> messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        messageLookup.addListener((Change<? extends ClientService, ? extends String> change) -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                messages.add(change.getValueAdded());
            }
            if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                messages.remove(change.getValueRemoved());
            }
        });

        Task<Void> serverTask = new Task<Void>() {

            private Random rng = new Random();

            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                int nClients = rng.nextInt(11);
                for (int i = 1 ; i <= nClients; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(rng.nextInt(2000)+500);
                    ClientService cs = new ClientService();
                    String clientID = "Client "+i ;
                    updateMessage("Connected "+clientID);
                    cs.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMessage, newMessage) -> {
                        messageLookup.put(cs, clientID +": " +newMessage);
                    });
                    Platform.runLater(cs::start);
                }
                return null ;
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(serverTask);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

        Label statusLabel =  new Label();
        statusLabel.textProperty().bind(serverTask.messageProperty());

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setItems(new SortedList<String>(messages, String::compareTo));

        VBox root = new VBox(5, listView, statusLabel);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class ClientService extends Service<Void> {

        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            Task<Void> task =  new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                   Random rng = new Random();
                   for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
                       Thread.sleep((rng.nextInt(1000)+500));
                       updateMessage("Step "+i);
                   }
                   return null ;
                }
            };
            return task ;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @James_D. The second solution looks good in my case, but when I run the code, I got java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. Debugging shows the exception occurs while executing the line 'messageLookup.put(cs, newMessage));'. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: How are you creating `messageLookup`? I omitted the initialization originally (now fixed).

Comment: Yes I realized messageLookup was not initialized. I initialized like in your fixed code. I also tried using MapProperty for ObservableMap and initialize it with SimpleMapProperty, but throws the same Exception. Further debugging indicates, the Exception occurs at fireValueChangedEvent() in StringPropertyBase.java!

Comment: Any suggestion for solving the Exception problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, so no. Note there was a threading bug in your code: I updated the answer with a fix for it. Not sure if that is the issue or not. Also updated the answer with my test code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @James_D for the complete runnable code. It works as I wanted. I will try to figure out what's missing in my code and adapt from the idea provided from your codes. Have  a good day!